# Is it worth setting up my own infrastructure for my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services

I'm new to rails and I am redoing and revamping my current website with it. I have been looking all over the internet about how to deploy my rails app to my server. It seems that everyone is mentioning AWS and Heroku. The problem is that I am not interested in paying money down the road when my website starts to grow.

So would it be worth it to set up my own infrastructure so I can change and modify it as my site grows or is it north worth the trouble for the prices that I could pay for someone (Heroku most likely) to worry about that for me?

Also is it even possible or feasible for that matter to deploy myself?

Thanks

TopGunCoder

Comment: depends on if you class yourself as a competent enough sysadmin to admin the server and how much you value your time doing it versus paying Heroku to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few rails projects hosted on my own virtual server. Ubuntu, rbenv, git, rails, passenger and mysql setup.. There are other setups, for example with unicorn an nginx..it really depends on your projects.

How many hits you'll expect per day/month?

I can recommend hosting little projects by your own. It is cheaper and very convenient. But you need know-how and time.

And the state-of-the art method for deploying rails apps is the capistrano tool.

Comment: At the moment I don't even expect there to be many hits. There won't be any pertinent information and it will be a front end for a database  development project I will be doing for someone. They will be the only ones ever logging in to check its progress and usability.

Comment: That sounds like a staging environment? You could use heroku ore some similar provider. You won't need AWS if you don't have any uploads or something like that. Heroku free plan..